# Python: Issue Deprecation warning when importing a function

Tags: python, module, warnings, deprecated

in a file `B.py` I have a function hello(). The location is deprecated and I moved it to `A.py`.

Currently I do:

```
def hello():
    from A import hello as new_hello
    warnings.warn(
        "B.hello() is deprecated. Use A.hello() instead.",
        DeprecationWarning
    )
    return new_hello()
```

but this issues the warning when the function is called. I want to issue the warning when the function is imported. Is it possible to issue a warning if a function is imported like this:

```
from B import hello
```

`B.py` also has some other functions, which are not deprecated.

Comment: You basically want to patch `builtins.__import__` to inspect its `args[0]` (module `name`) and `args[4]` (`fromlist`). Raise a warning if `args[0].endswith('B')` and `'hello' in args[4]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a decorator on the function should work, the warning will be shown when the function is imported or called. Please double check that the function is not executed on import (it shouldn't be).

```py
import warnings
import functools

def deprecated_decorator(func):
    warnings.warn("This method is depreciated")

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@deprecated_decorator
def test_method(num_1, num_2):
    print('I am a method executing' )
    x = num_1 + num_2
    return x

# Test if method returns normally
# x = test_method(1, 2)
# print(x)
```

Comment: This fires off the warning weth `B.py` is imported, though...

Comment: @Maximilian 's comment also implies that even if you import another function by name from the same module (`from B import some_non_deprecated_method`), it will also give you the same warning (spuriously). This makes it unusable for my use case (leave the function in the same module but rename it; warn only when importing the deprecated name).

Comment: It has been a while. Should I undo accepting this answer?

Comment: Yes good point this fires when B imported. ijoseph if you can write full answer based on your method in comments it would be appropriate to accept that as accepted answer.